# I want to play AisleRiot Solitaire but don't know how to start it

Tags: software-center, games

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04. I am new to Ubuntu (or any Linux type OS for that matter). I go to Ubuntu Software Center then games, double click on AisleRiot Solitaire & see that it is installed. Now how do I start the game. The way it reads, it suggests there is more than one game but I see no list nor any clickable icon to get a list or start a game. Started on a Commodore 64 many years agoforgot what it was like to be this lost. Appreciate any help

Answer (score 1):

Simply click on Ubuntu dash icon in the top left,
and start typing the name of the game, i.e. solitaire.

The icon for the game should appear, just click on it and the game
should start.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dpkg -L` in a terminal to see the installed files:

```
$ dpkg -L aisleriot
/.
/usr
/usr/games
/usr/games/sol
/usr/share
/usr/share/applications
/usr/share/applications/sol.desktop
/usr/share/aisleriot
/usr/share/aisleriot/icons
/usr/share/aisleriot/icons/hicolor
[...]
```

You can launch the game from the terminal with `/usr/games/sol` .

Alternately, you can click on the Ubuntu icon on the top left to open the dash (or press the Windows key or equivalent) and start typing.

Typing either "aisle" or "sol" will show you the icon to launch the game.  Click it to run.

Answer (score 0):

The list of games is on the dropdown menu.
After you start AisleRiot Solitaire ->Game->Select Game.  Then choose which game you want to play.